# Download multiple(consecutive) txt from multiple(consecutive day)URLs

Tags: python, pandas, request

I'd like to download multiple txt that saves data by day.
The address is like this:
http://100.200.100.200/cd200730.txt

I'd like to download those txt files with start and end data input. I've made it through until I get all URLs but haven't found a way to download and save each file with its name of the day. - "cd200730.txt", "cd200731.txt", etc

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# set date_range to start and end
date_range=pd.date_range(start='2018-04-24', end='2018-04-27', freq='D')
df=date_range.strftime('%y%m%d')
df2=df.to_frame(index=False,name='date')
df2['date'] = df2['date'].apply(lambda x: f"http://100.200.100.200/cd{x}.txt")

for url in df2.date:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open(url, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://10.47.149.67/cd180424.txt'
```

When I run it with changed last line,`"open('url.txt'...)"`, I get only the last file.

I feel like I should make another for loop in the part of "open(url)".
Is there any I can complete this work?

> ---Edited--- v0.1

I've made it through as following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# date_range to start and end
date_range=pd.date_range(start='2018-04-24', end='2018-04-25', freq='D')
df=date_range.strftime('%y%m%d')
df_filename=df.to_frame(index=False,name='file_name')
df_filename['file_name']=df_filename['file_name'].apply(lambda x: f"cd{x}.txt")
df2=df.to_frame(index=False,name='date')
df2['date'] = df2['date'].apply(lambda x: f"http://100.200.100.200/cd{x}.txt")

for url in df2.date:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    for name in df_filename['file_name']:
        open(name, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

> ---Edited--- v0.2

"v0.1" only saves the same data with various date files (cd200718.csv and cd200719 have the same data)
Something little is missing..

> ---Edited--- v0.3

Finnaly, the following works perfectly!

```
for url,name in zip(df2.date,df_filename['file_name']):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    open(name, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: ``open(url..)`` is a invalid os path, it should be ``open(<local system path>..)``

Comment: Shouldn't it refer to the list of links to download? It saves data ("url.txt") in the working current directory when I put "url.txt" there.